# Google Map toolbar on Android does not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, toolbar

I am working with google maps API, and i have created a custom infowindow for the markers.

I need to show the toolbar maps, but using this method

```java
map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
```

when I click the marker, it is shown my infowindow  but not the toolbar.

[image: google maps needs example]

I would like to show the toolbar whenever the marker has been clicked.

Below is my code:

```java
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                MarkerCouple idtype = (MarkerCouple) marker.getTag();

                if (idtype.getType() == ResourceType.EVENTS 
                     && currentEvents.get(idtype.getID()) != null) {

                    Resources resources = currentResources
                            .get(currentEvents.get(idtype.getID()).getRes_ID());
                    Events event = currentEvents.get(idtype.getID());

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowEventActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra(Variable.USER_JSON, user.toJSON());
                    i.putExtra(Variable.EVENT_JSON, event.toJSON());
                    i.putExtra(Variable.RESOURCE_JSON, resources.toJSON());

                    startActivityForResult(i, Variable.SHOW_EVENT);
                }

                if (idtype.getType() == ResourceType.PLACES
                     && currentPlaces.get(idtype.getID()) != null) {
                    Resources resources = currentResources
                            .get(currentPlaces.get(idtype.getID()).getRes_ID());
                    Places place = currentPlaces.get(idtype.getID());

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowPlaceActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra(Variable.USER_JSON, user.toJSON());
                    i.putExtra(Variable.PLACE_JSON, place.toJSON());
                    i.putExtra(Variable.RESOURCE_JSON, resources.toJSON());

                    startActivityForResult(i, Variable.SHOW_PLACE);
                }
            }
        });

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_preview, null);
                ImageView m = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_image);
                m.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageToShow, 600, 400, true));
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }
        });
        new MarkerAsync().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        MarkerCouple idtype = (MarkerCouple) marker.getTag();

        if (idtype.getType() == ResourceType.EVENTS && currentEvents.get(idtype.getID()) != null) {
            Events event = currentEvents.get(idtype.getID());
            final Resources resources = currentResources.get(event.getRes_ID());
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).invalidate(Variable.DOWNLOAD_URL + resources.getURI());
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        imageToShow = Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(Variable.DOWNLOAD_URL + resources.getURI()).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                }
            }.execute();
        }


        if (idtype.getType() == ResourceType.PLACES && currentPlaces.get(idtype.getID()) != null) {
            Places place = currentPlaces.get(idtype.getID());
            final Resources resources = currentResources.get(place.getRes_ID());
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).invalidate(Variable.DOWNLOAD_URL + resources.getURI());
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).invalidate(Variable.DOWNLOAD_URL + resources.getURI());
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        imageToShow = Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(Variable.DOWNLOAD_URL + resources.getURI()).get();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                }
            }.execute();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `return false;` from your `onMarkerClick()`

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener):

> **public abstract boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker)**
>
> **Returns**
>
> true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur), false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera to move to the marker and an info window to appear.

Comment: If i return false, i throw exception

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                 at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:591)
                                                                 at tesi.myview.MainActivity$3.getInfoWindow(MainActivity.java:274)

Comment: It seems that your `imageToShow` is null when your `getInfoWindow` is called

Comment: I need the default behavior only for toolbar because i need to show my custom infowindow

Comment: IT WORKS, THANKS SO MUCH!